# page with login control does not load when uploaded to server

Tags: asp.net, mono

i have a simple program my ASP.NET 4 unleashed book. when i run it on visualstudio, i get the login page. which is correct but when i load it in the server, i get this error:

Runtime error
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Details: Requested URL: /login.aspx

my question is how is this url being requested.

my files are:

```
**web.config**
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>

**SecretFiles/web.config**
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

**SecretFiles/Secret.aspx**
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>This Page is Secret!</h1>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

**Login.aspx**
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" CreateUserUrl="~/Register.aspx" CreateUserText="Register">
        </asp:Login>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

**Register**
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/SecretFiles/Secret.aspx" />


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I don't know what the problem is. I am using an ubuntu server with apache and modmono. i believe that what may be occuring is that it may be trying to find login page at /login.aspx but the correct location would be /AspFolder/LoginCtrl/Login.aspx. if i am correct, how do i go about making the changes i need to.

Answer (score 0):

change the permission (chmod 755 yourdirectory) on your web directory and try it.

Comment: what should i actually type: sudo chmod 755 /AspFolder/LoginCtrl/web.config or what? because i have, ive also done it on /AspFolder, /AspFolder/LoginCtrl, /AspFolder/Login.aspx.cs, as well as /AspFolder/LoginCtrl/Login.aspx. but i get the same problem each time.

Answer (score 0):

i found out the problem.
ok my folder with the project is located in

```
/var/www/html/AspFolder/LoginCtrl
```

my login page is located at:

```
/LoginCtrl/Login.aspx
```

in order to access this page i have to go to the web.config of server **(not project folder)** which is located at

```
/var/www/html/web.config
```

and put the following:

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
        <forms loginUrl="/AspFolder/LoginCtrl/Login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```